# Why are unsigned numbers implemented?

Tags: numbers

I can't figure out why microprocessor systems implement unsigned numbers.
I guess the cost is just double the number of conditional branches,
since greater than, less than, .etc, need a different algorithm than signed,
still are there any algorithms that unsigned numbers are a significant advantage for?

my question partly is why they need to be in the instruction set as
opposed to be supported by a compiler?

Comment: Many storage formats use unsigned types.  For example, jpg, text documents, etc...

Comment: im not sure i understand that answer, i think java only supports signed numbers and you can write code for jpg, text etc, what im dont understand is why unsigned are used

Comment: Basically the unsigned numbers are the standard, signed are implemented to provide negative numbers.

Comment: i know they have been in the C language since the late 1960s, im not questioning that, what i not sure of is why, ie what are the advantages

Comment: A lot of the world's data is non-numeric.  Non-numeric data is easily manipulated using unsigned types.  That Java doesn't have unsigned numeric types is a failing, which causes a lot of bugs in things that have to manipulate non-numeric data (e.g. compression, etc..).

Comment: @jtw Erik says there is no such thing as a negative pixel color or a negative character. So it would be wasteful to use signed integers for that, you would give up half of the address space.

Comment: thank you for responses, i guess the extra cost of unsigned numbers at the processor level is double the number of branches since the tests are different. If you are dealing with binary data which doesnt represent numbers then you are not going to be using these tests anyway, so then the fact a bit of image data looks like a negative number is irrelevant

Comment: @jtw , what extra cost? It's been awhile since I've studied two's complement math, but I'm pretty sure it works the same for signed and unsigned in most cases.

Comment: i thought the whole RISC idea was to have the minimum set of instructions implemented in the hardware, so having a set of instructions to deal with unsigned comes with a price. I am persuaded by your point below that some algorithms are easier for the human to think of as bit patterns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using unsigned integers in c, c++](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225949/using-unsigned-integers-in-c-c)

Comment: @MartinMaat Half your address space but only one bit out of the item in question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm alone here, but I find it surprisingly rare that I need *signed integers* when developing applications. Almost all of the time what I need is either an (unsigned) natural number (a positive size, usually), or a signed floating-point number. Exceptions are things like currency, but those are very rare; to me, unsigned integers are the norm and signed integers are the exception!

Comment: From a CPU's perspective, pretty much all numbers are unsigned. A few instructions can interpret the bits as signed (.e.g. arithmetic-right-shift), but really [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) lets the CPU treat signed integers as unsigned integers, meaning no (or very little) special circuitry is required by the CPU to support both.

Comment: Can you explain the fundamental premise of your question? Why do you think that unsigned numbers are "lesser" ones? Why shouldn't processors just support unsigned numbers, and let compilers implement signed arithmetic? Anyway two's-complement makes most operations (and comparisons) identical. Sure there's a couple differences, so a handful more "wires" and transistors must be added to a chip design, but that's negligible. And having them sit unused on the processor circuitry doesn't incur notable runtime cost either.

Comment: The tests are exactly the same. Perhaps you should read up on how CPUs work :) In particular, two's complement signed numbers behave exactly the same way as unsigned numbers, and guess what representation of signed numbers modern CPUs use? If you want to understand CPU architecture, you need to learn how CPUs are designed. There's no shortcut. There's only very few CPU instructions that distinguish between signed and unsigned numbers, and they all have to do with the way overflow is handled. And historically, there were many ways of encoding signed integers - two's complement "won".

Comment: have to disagree about that, the greater than less than tests are different if the number are signed vs unsigned

Comment: @jtw: the RISC idea wasn't to use the minimum set of instructions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer), but to reduce the instruction set to the instructions that compilers actually output and find useful. BTW, I don't think ARM can be considered RISC in the same way that MIPS, SPARC, PowerPC, HPPA and AArch64 are RISC.

Comment: @ErikEidt You are right that a lot of data is non-numeric and using unsigned integers is the natural representation. However, I argue that unsigned integers in Java create excessive complexity, with little benefits in performance or expressiveness: https://www.nayuki.io/page/unsigned-int-considered-harmful-for-java

Comment: If you design a CPU using two's complement, it's basically free. If we have a demand to add AES instruction to every single > 50$ CPU on the planet, we can support unsigned numbers.

Comment: A better question is why aren't arbitrarily bounded numeric types implemented? My top ten list doesn't need an 11th entry. :P

Comment: @Marco13: It would have been helpful if C had distinguished between types used to represent non-negative quantities versus those used to represent members of a wrapping algebraic ring (e.g. for a 16-bit unsigned value, the set of integers congruent mod 65536).  C's unsigned types are an awwkward hybrid of both, when most usage cases really need one or the other.

Comment: I'm baffled to see that nobody has replied "Because unsigned numbers are more *natural*" yet.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, of course, this was bogus. The point of **unsigned** is exactly to have the mod 2^32 behavior. I'll delete these (misleading) comments in a second.

Comment: Nevertheless, there are seome potentially relevant points in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395205/why-are-unsigned-integers-error-prone  as well.

Comment: @Daerdemandt: The algebraic ring of integers congruent mod 2^16, or 2^32, or 2^64, are natural constructs, but both unsigned and silent-wrapping two's-complement math use the same ring but simply label half of the items differently.

Answer (score 39):

Unsigned numbers are one interpretation of a sequence of bits. It is also the simplest, and most used interpretation internally to the CPU because addresses, and op codes are simply bits. Memory / Stack addressing and arithmetic are the foundations of microprocessor, well, processing. Moving up the abstraction pyramid, another frequent interpretation of bits is as a character (ASCII, Unicode, EBCDIC). Then there are other interpretations such as IEEE Floating point, RGBA for graphics, and so on.  None of these are simple signed numbers (IEEE FP is not simple, and the arithmetic using those is very complicated).

Also, with unsigned arithmetic it is pretty straight forward (if not most efficiently) to implement the others . The converse is not true.

Comment: EBCDIC has only one "I".

Comment: @Ruslan - but it's **pronounced** like it has two. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker no it isn't.  EBCDIC is pronounced **eb**-see-dick.

Answer (score 19):

The bulk of the hardware cost for comparison operations is the subtraction.  The output of the subtraction used by comparison is essentially three bits of state:

- whether all the bits are zero (i.e. the equal condition),
- the sign bit of the result
- the carry bit of the subtraction (i.e. the 33rd high order bit on a 32-bit computer)

With the proper combination of testing these three bits after the subtraction operation, we can determine all the signed relational operations, as well as all the unsigned relational operations (these bits are also how overflow is detected, signed vs. unsigned).  The same basic ALU hardware can be shared to implement all these comparisons (not to mention the subtraction instruction), until the final checking of those three bits of state, which differs as per the relational comparison desired.  So, it is not a lot of extra hardware.

The only real cost is the need for the encoding of additional modes of comparison in the instruction set architecture, which may marginally decrease instruction density.  Still, it is pretty normal that hardware has lot of instructions that aren't used by any given language.

Comment: Comparison of unsigned numbers does not require subtraction. it may be achieved by left to right bitwise comparison.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne But that's not how processors implement it. On the contrary, it's almost unthinkable for a 2's-complement processor not to implement subtraction (with or without carry/borrow) in its ALU. The immediate afterwards thought of a designer is to use this necessary ALU to kill another bird with the same stone, comparison. Comparison then simply becomes a subtraction where the result is not written back to the register file.

Comment: +1: this is the correct answer to the question asked.  Summarising: *because implementing unsigned operations is almost free when you've already implemented signed*.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta It also works the other way around. Signed and unsigned numbers in modern CPUs are almost identical, which is the main point the OP didn't recognize. Even the comparison instructions are the same for signed and unsigned - that's one of the reasons why two's complement won the signed integer wars :)

Comment: That it "doesn't cost much" to implement them isn't *why we have them.* ... I imagine there are plenty of things that would be cheap to implement that are not offered because *nobody needs them.* So.. given that they're cheap to keep around, why do we even want them?

Comment: @svidgen> as other answers told, it works the other way around. Primary concern is unsigned numbers, which are used for basically everything (memory address, io/ports, character representations, …). Signed numbers just come cheap once you have unsigned, and come in handy in the rare event that they are desirable.

Comment: @svidgen - the question asked was predicated on the assumption that unsigned numbers are expensive to implement.  So the answer is "actually, they're really cheap to implement".  "Given that unsigned numbers are cheap, still, what is the point" is a different (valid) question.

Answer (score 14):

Because, if you need to count something that is *always* `>= 0`, you would unnecessarily cut your counting space in half using signed integers.

Consider the auto-incremented INT PK you might be putting on your database tables. If you use a signed integer there, your table stores HALF as many records as it *could* for the same field size with NO benefit.

Or the octets of an RGBa color. We don't want to awkwardly start counting this naturally positive-number concept at a negative number. A signed number would either break the mental model or halve our space. An unsigned integer not only matches the concept, but provides twice the resolution.

From the hardware perspective, unsigned integers are simple. They're probably the easiest bit structure to perform math on. And, no doubt, we could simplify the hardware by simulating integer types (or even floating point!) in a compiler. So, **why are both unsigned *and* signed integers implemented in *hardware?***

Well ... **performance!**

It's more efficient to implement signed integers in hardware than it is in software. The hardware can be instructed to perform math on either type of integer in a single instruction. And that's *very good*, because the hardware smashes bits together *more or less* in parallel. If you try to simulate that in software, the integer-type that you choose to "simulate" will undoubtedly require *many* instructions and be *noticeably* slower.

Comment: Along these lines, you can save yourself an operation when doing array bounds checking. If you use an unsigned integer, you only need to check that the provided index is less than the array size (because it can't be negative).

Comment: Why can't the database store negative row IDs?

Comment: @dan04 It certainly can... But, if you're using an auto-incrementing int starting at 0 or 1, which is pretty common practice, you've precluded the use of half of your available numbers. And while you could conceivably start counting at -2^31 (or whatever), you'll have a potential "edge" case in the middle of your id space.

Comment: Let's not get hung up on the database use case though. It's just an example to demonstrate that you sometimes don't even need to account for a value being negative. And you might actually be wasting a bit if you *do* account for it. Or even adding more bounds checking to keep that bit around

Comment: Cutting your field in half is kind of a weak argument though. Chances are if your app requires more than 2 billion, it also requires more than 4 billion.

Comment: @corsiKa: by that reason, if it requires more than 4, it likely requires 8, then 16, etc. Where does it end?

Comment: @whatsisname generally, you use integer types of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits. Saying that unsigned is better because you get all 32 bits instead of the *limited* range of 31 bits of positive integer space in a signed byte is a not going to matter much in most cases.

Comment: @corsika the other answers pretty much tell us that "it doesn't cost us anything to keep unsigned integers around." But they fail to give a reason you'd actually want to use one, which, barring a significant performance difference, is simply the extra bit of positive number space. ... Frankly, it doesn't matter if nothing *you* can imagine needs it. There are no other compelling reasons you'd actually *use* one. ... Or be offered the option.

Comment: Side note: I had no idea this answer would be even remotely controversial! ... Seems to me there was a time when you just used as few bits as you could to do what you need. Whether to preserve RAM, disk space, network traffic, or to enable efficient packing. And in many cases, that just meant using an unsigned integer. ... And still does, in some cases, by my understanding...

Comment: @svidgen I can certainly think of situations that would seem logical to have it. What I'm saying is there are far more expensive things to worry about these days. The vast, vast majority of programmers are not in situations where they should even be putting thought into "will this be inefficient if I use an int64 instead of an int32?" Most programmers these days worry about things like "I hope those stupid business users don't reject the latest build because that one screen has the wrong shade of mauve in the css."

Comment: @corsiKa Sure -- I mostly write and customize business apps and other web apps too. 99% of the time, I *don't* care whether I'm dealing with a signed versus an unsigned integer. But, the question is pretty general, clearly not limited to the concerns of "most developers." ... Though, if you'll forgive the cheekiness, you *would* have the wrong shade of mauve if your CSS were restricted to `(2^7)^3` colors! (At least where I work!)

Answer (score 9):

Your question consists of two parts:

1. What is the purpose of unsigned integers?
2. Are unsigned integers worth the trouble?

#### 1. What is the purpose of unsigned integers?

Unsigned numbers, quite simply, represent a class of quantities for which negative values are meaningless.  Sure, you might say that the answer to the question of "how many apples do I have?" might be a negative number if you owe some apples to someone, but what about the question of "how much memory do I have?" --you cannot have a negative amount of memory.  So, unsigned integers are very suitable for representing such quantities, and they have the benefit of being able to represent twice the range of positive values than signed integers can.  For example, the maximum value you can represent with a 16-bit signed integer is 32767, while with a 16-bit unsigned integer it is 65535.

#### 2. Are unsigned integers worth the trouble?

Unsigned integers do not really represent any trouble, so, yes, they are worth it. You see, they do not require an extra set of "algorithms"; the circuitry required to implement them is a subset of the circuitry required for implementing signed integers.

A CPU does not have one multiplier for signed integers and a different multiplier for unsigned ones; it has just one multiplier, which works in a slightly different way depending on the nature of the operation. Supporting signed multiplication requires a tiny bit more circuitry than unsigned, but since it needs to be supported anyway, unsigned multiplication comes practically for free, it is included in the package.

As for addition and subtraction, there is no difference in the circuitry at all.  If you read up on the so-called **two's complement representation of integers** you will find that it is so cleverly designed that these operations can be performed in exactly the same way, regardless of the nature of the integers.

Comparison also works the same way, since it is nothing but subtract-and-discard-the-result, the only difference is in the conditional branch (jump) instructions, which work by looking at different flags of the CPU which are set by the preceding (comparison) instruction.  In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617990/773113 you can find an explanation of how they work on the Intel x86 architecture. What happens is that the designation of a conditional jump instruction as signed or unsigned depends on which flags it examines.

Comment: my question assumed all this, by algorithm i meant the rule for less than greater than etc were different. The cost I see is having lots of extra instructions. If high level programs like to see data as patterns of bits this can be easily implemented say by a compiler

Comment: @jtw - but the point is that those extra instructions are actually *very similar* to the instructions required for signed numbers, and *almost all of the circuitry required for them can be shared*.  The extra cost of implementing both types is almost zero.

Comment: yes that answers my question, adding the extra branch instructions comes with a small cost and they are often useful in practice

Comment: *"Unsigned operations require some extra handling when it comes to division and multiplication"* I think you have that backwards. Multiplication and division are easier with unsigned values. The extra handling is required to deal with signed operands.

Comment: @CodyGray I knew someone would show up to say this.  You are right, of course.  This is the reasoning behind my statement, which I originally omitted for the sake of brevity: a CPU could not possibly offer unsigned-only multiplication and division, because the signed versions are so useful.  As a matter of fact, signed multiplication and division are a must; unsigned are optional.  Therefore, if unsigned is to be _also_ offered, this can be seen as requiring a tiny bit more circuitry.

Comment: I see what you're saying. And it makes sense, that is the argument being made in several of the other answers. But in service of brevity, your answer as it stands appears to be making an incorrect assertion. (And yes, I showed up just to say this. Sorry. :-) Maybe say something like, "A CPU does not need one multiplier for signed integers and a different multiplier for unsigned ones; it has just one multiplier, which works in a slightly different way depending on the nature of the operation. And since signed mul needs to be supported anyway, unsigned mul almost falls out for free." ?

Comment: @CodyGray I amended my answer.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 7):

Microprocessors are inherently unsigned.
The signed numbers are the thing that's implemented, not the other way around.

Computers can and do work fine without signed numbers, but it us, humans that need negative numbers, hence signedness was invented.

Comment: Many microprocessors have both signed and unsigned instructions for various operations.

Comment: @whatsisname: It's the opposite: many microprocessors have only unsigned instructions. A **few** have signed instructions. This is because with 2s-complement arithmetic the bit value is the same regardless of weather the number is signed or unsigned and how one reads the number is only a matter of interpretation - hence it is easier to implement it as a compiler feature. Generally only old micros that assume programmers don't use compilers have fancy signed instructions to make assembly code readable.

Answer (score 3):

Because they have one more bit that is easily available for storage, and you don't have to worry about negative numbers. There's not much more to it than that.

Now if you need an example of where you would *need* this extra bit, there are plenty to be found if you look.

My favorite example comes from bitboards in Chess engines. There are 64 squares on a chess board, thus an `unsigned long` provides perfect storage for a variety of algorithms revolving around move generation. Considering the fact that you need to binary operations (as well as shift operations!!), it is easy to see why it is easier not to have to worry about what special things happen if the MSB is set. It can be done with signed long, but it is a **lot** easier to use unsigned.

Answer (score 3):

Having a pure maths background, this is a slightly more mathematical take for anybody interested.

If we start with an 8bit signed and unsigned integer, what we have is basically the integers modulo 256, so far as addition and multiplication is concerned, provided 2's complement is used to represent negative integers (and this is how every modern processor does it).

Where things differ is in two places: one is comparison operations. In a sense, the integers modulo 256 are best considered a circle of numbers (like the integers modulo 12 do on an old-fashioned analog clockface). To make numerical comparisons (is x < y) meaningful, we needed to decide which numbers are less than others. From the mathematician's point of view, we want to embed the integers modulo 256 into the set of all integers somehow. Mapping the 8bit integer whose binary representation is all zeros to the integer 0 is the obvious thing to do. We can then proceed to map others so that '0+1' (the result of zeroing a register, say ax, and the incrementing it by one, via 'inc ax') goes to the integer 1, and so on. We can do the same with -1, for example mapping '0-1' to the integer -1, and '0-1-1' to the integer -2. We must ensure that this embedding is a function, so cannot map a single 8bit integer to two integers. As such, this means that if we map all the numbers into the set of integers, 0 will be there, along with some integers less than 0 and some more than 0. There are essentially 255 ways to do this with an 8bit integer (according to what minimum you want, from 0 to -255). Then you can define 'x < y' in terms of '0 < y - x'.

There are two common use cases, for which hardware support is sensible: one with all nonzero integers being greater than 0, and one with an approximately 50/50 split around 0. All other possibilities are easily emulated by translating numbers via an extra 'add and sub' before operations, and the need for this is so rare than I can't think of an explicit example in modern software (since you can just work with a larger mantissa, say 16 bits).

The other issue is that of mapping an 8bit integer into the space of 16bit integers. Does -1 go to -1? This is what you want if 0xFF is meant to represent -1. In this case, sign-extending is the sensible thing to do, so that 0xFF goes to 0xFFFF. On the other hand, if 0xFF was meant to represent 255, then you want it mapped to 255, hence to 0x00FF, rather than 0xFFFF.

This is the difference between the 'shift' and 'arithmetic shift' operations as well.

Ultimately, however, it comes down to the fact that int's in software are not integers, but representations in binary, and only some can be represented. When designing hardware, choices have to be made as to which to do natively in hardware. Since with 2's complement the addition and multiplication operations are identical, it makes sense to represent negative integers this way. Then it is only a matter of operations which depend on which integers your binary representations are meant to represent.

Comment: I like the mathematical approach, but instead of thinking merely of promotion to a specific larger size, I think it's nicer to generalize in terms of operations on an infinite-length binary numbers.  Subtract 1 from any number whose rightmost k digits are 0 and the rightmost k digits of the result will be 1, and one can prove by induction that if one carried out math with an infinite number of bits, every bit would be 1.  For unsigned math, one ignores all but the bottom bits of a number.

Answer (score 2):

Lets examine the implementation cost for adding unsigned integers to a CPU design with existing signed integers.

A typical CPU needs the following arithmetic instructions:

- ADD (which adds two values and sets a flag if the operation overflows)
- SUB (which subtracts one value from another and sets various flags -- we'll discuss these below)
- CMP (which is essentially 'SUB and discard the result, only keep the flags')
- LSH (left shift, set a flag on overflow)
- RSH (right shift, set a flag if a 1 is shifted out)
- Variants of all of the above instructions that handle carrying/borrowing from the flags, thus letting you chain the instructions together conveniently to operate on larger types than the CPU registers
- MUL (multiply, set flags, etc -- not universally available)
- DIV (divide, set flags, etc -- a lot of CPU architectures lack this)
- Move from a smaller integer type (e.g. 16-bit) to a larger one (e.g. 32-bit).  For signed integers, this is usually called MOVSX (move with sign extend).

It also needs logical instructions:

- Branch on zero
- Branch on greater
- Branch on less
- Branch on overflow
- Negated versions of all of the above

To perform the above branches on signed integer comparisons, the easiest way is to have the SUB instruction set the following flags:

- Zero. Set if the subtraction resulted in a value of zero.
- Overflow. Set if the subtraction borrowed a value from the most significant bit.
- Sign. Set to the result's sign bit.

Then the arithmetic branches are implemented as follows:

- Branch on zero: if zero flag is set
- Branch on less: if the sign flag is different to the overflow flag
- Branch on greater: if the sign flag is equal to the overflow flag, and the zero flag is clear.

The negations of these should follow obviously from how those are implemented.

So your existing design already implements all of these for signed integers.  Now lets consider what we need to do to add unsigned integers:

- ADD -- the implementation of ADD is identical.
- SUB -- we need to add an extra flag: the carry flag is set when a value is borrowed from beyond the register's most significant bit.
- CMP -- doesn't change
- LSH -- doesn't change
- RSH -- the right shift for signed values retains the value of the most significant bit.  For unsigned values, we should instead set it to zero.
- MUL -- if your output size is the same as input, no special handling is required (x86 *does* have special handling, but only because it has output into a register pair, but note that this facility is actually quite rarely used, so would be a more obvious candidate to leave out of a processor than unsigned types)
- DIV -- no changes required
- Move from smaller type to larger type -- need to add MOVZX, move with zero extend.  Note that MOVZX is *extremely* simple to implement.
- Branch on zero -- unchanged
- Branch on less -- jumps when carry flag set.
- Branch on greater -- jumps if carry flag and zero both clear.

Note that in each case, the modifications are *very simple*, and can be implemented simply by gating a small section of circuitry on or off, or by adding a new flag register than can be controlled by a value that needs to be calculated as part of the instruction's implementation anyway.

Therefore, the cost of adding unsigned instructions is *very small*.  As to why it *should  be done*, note that memory addresses (and offsets in arrays) are inherently unsigned values.  As programs spend a lot of time manipulating memory addresses, having a type that handles them correctly makes the programs easier to write.

Comment: thank you, this answers my question, the cost is small and the instructions are frequently useful

Comment: Unsigned double-size multiplication is essential when doing multi-precision arithmetic, and is probably good for a better than 2x overall speed improvement when performing RSA encryption.  Also, division is different in the signed and unsigned cases, but since the unsigned case is easier and division is rare enough and slow enough that adding a few instructions won't hurt much, the simplest thing to do would be to implement *only* unsigned division and then wrap it with some sign-handling logic.

Answer (score 2):

Unsigned numbers exist largely to handle situations where one needs a wrapping algebraic ring (for a 16-bit unsigned type, it would be the ring of integers congruent mod 65536).  Take a value, add any amount less than the modulus, and the difference between the two values will be the amount that was added.  As a real-world example, if a utility meter reads 9995 at the start of a month and one uses 23 units, the meter will read 0018 at the end of the month.  When using an algebraic-ring type, there's no need to do anything special to deal with overflow.  Subtracting 9995 from 0018 will yield 0023, precisely the number of units that were used.

On the PDP-11, the machine for which C was first implemented, there were
no unsigned integer types but signed types could be used for modular
arithmetic which wrapped between 32767 and -32768 rather than between
65535 and 0.  The integer instructions on some other platforms did not
wrap things cleanly, however; rather than requiring that implementations
must emulate the two's-complement integers used in the PDP-11, the language
instead added unsigned types which *mostly* had to behave as algebraic
rings, and allowed signed integer types to behave in other ways in case of
overflow.

In the early days of C, there were many quantities which could exceed
32767 (the common INT_MAX) but not 65535 (the common UINT_MAX).  It
thus became common to use unsigned types to hold such quantities (e.g.
size_t).  Unfortunately, there is nothing in the language to distinguish
between types that should behave like numbers with an extra bit of
positive range, versus types that should behave like algebraic rings.
Instead, the language makes types smaller than "int" behave like numbers
while full-sized types behave like algebraic rings.  Consequently, calling
function like:

```
uint32_t mul(uint16_t a, uint16_t b) { return a*b; }
```

with (65535, 65535) will have one defined behavior on systems where `int` is 16 bits (i.e. return 1), a different behavior where `int` is 33 bits or larger (return 0xFFFE0001), and Undefined Behavior on systems where "int" is anywhere in-between [note that gcc will *usually* yield arithmetically-correct results with results between INT_MAX+1u and UINT_MAX, but will sometimes generate code for the above function which fails with such values!].  Not very helpful.

Still, the lack of types which behave consistently like numbers or consistently like an algebraic ring does not change the fact that algebraic ring types are almost indispensable for some kinds of programming.